# sails.js: how to find items inside a model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js

I am trying to get values inside a model. for instance: the model (Parking) that i have is:

```
 {
 "age":34,
 "invitation": "737073139",
    "locations": [
          {"name": "loc a ","zone":"zone a"},
          {"name": "loc b ","zone":"zone b"}
          ]
}
```

I tried the following but without success:

```
Parking.find({'locations.name':{ contains: 'loc a' }
}).done(function (err, response) {res.json({ success:true,ok: response}, 200);
});
```

What I'm trying to get is the location structure with the name:"loc a"..zone... etc. Is it possible to do this with sailsjs?

Answer (score 0):

*Is it possible to do this with sailsjs?*

Frankly speaking i have never worked on **sailjs**, but you can do this with ngforeach loop of angular as i can see in your tags.

You can do this with angular:

```
var dummy=[];

angular.forEach(Parking.locations, function(item, key) {
  if(item.name === "loc a" && item.zone === "zone a"){
     dummy.push(item.name);
  }
});
```